# MVC 1.0.1 Changing password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my account controller when i click change password nothing happen. is there something wrong with my coding?

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordVM changePasswordVM, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ApplicationUser _User = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(_User, changePasswordVM.CurrentPassword, changePasswordVM.NewPassword);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (returnUrl == null)
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                else
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Password Change Attempt.");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Is your code even hitting this method?  We can't debug your code for you.

Comment: It appears though that you never handle the condition when the ModelState is invalid and it will just return the view back. Have you trapped or interrogated this for any modelstate errors?

Comment: Have edited and currently it is working

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordVM changePasswordVM, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        LeaveUser _User = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (changePasswordVM.NewPassword == changePasswordVM.ConfirmNewPassword)
            {
                var result = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(_User, changePasswordVM.CurrentPassword, changePasswordVM.NewPassword);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (returnUrl == null)
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    else
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Password Change Attempt. Password must be at least 8 characters.");
            }
        }
        return View();
```